# BootStrap remove offset when width < 1680

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have element that I want to col-lg-offset-2 if Browser width > 1681,

and I want to remove that offset in Browser width < 1680.

I have this problem because the only col I can use is "LG" Because of the resolution is higher than 1170px.

[Here](http://halomli.co.il/site/) is the link to the site, as you can see if you resize the browser all the navbar is going down.

Comment: You can use `xl` instead of `lg`

Comment: You probably misunderstood what bootstrap offset is for

Comment: @Aziz you can not use `xl` instead of `lg` in bootstrap.

Comment: @VishalPanara I think its an addon to the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use media query for that and don't use offset concept because offset can not work in your case. 
 just use the below solution. This media query is work for only Browser `width > 1680`.

---

```
@media (min-width: 1680px){ 
    .yourclass{
        margin-left: 16.6666%;
    }
}
```

---

`col-lg-offset-2` make the `margin-left:16.6666%` so you can use your custom class with same margin-left in media query.

Comment: Thank you, That help me.